# java boolean operators on enums

Tags: java, enums, boolean

In my c++ code i do stuff like this a lot

```
enum BarType {
    BT_UNKNOWN              = 0,
    BT_NORMAL               = 1,
    BT_BAR_REST             = 2,
    BT_REPEAT_PREV_MEASURES = 3,
    BT_TYPE_MASK            = 0x03,

    ... etc
};
BarType GetBarType(int bn)  { return (BarType)(m_barType[bn] & BT_TYPE_MASK); }
```

Is there a way to do this in java other than making everything ints which I hate because I like the type checking I get with enums?

Thanks

Comment: Java do have enum. Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: BTW, the first piece of code in this link is probably what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4531172/1488595

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest solution would be to use a [java.util.EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) for each mask. You can then test whether a given enum value is in the set corresponding to a mask.

Comment: thanks but that looks complex and slow and i do millions of these bit operations so i guess i'll have to stick with int

Comment: @steveh I don't think "looks complex and slow" is any substitute for measurement. As the documentation I linked to says: 'Enum sets are represented internally as bit vectors. This representation is extremely compact and efficient. The space and time performance of this class should be good enough to allow its use as a high-quality, typesafe alternative to traditional int-based "bit flags.'

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `values` array on the enum probably to achieve something like that.

```
 public enum BarType { BT_UNKNOWN, BT_NORMAL, BT_BAR_REST, BT_REPEAT }
 private static final int BT_TYPE_MASK = 0x03;

 public BarType getBarType(int bn) {
      return BarType.values()[bn & BT_TYPE_MASK]; 
 }
```

The order in `values` is the order in which the enum items are defined.

Comment: what is bn in your example? if its type BarType then the & doesn't work

Comment: It was according to your example supposed to be an int. Edited it to clarify (and fix a typo).